# JSON recursive traverse

Tags: java, json, jackson

My goal is to read unstructured JSON file and load that file into database:

Basically I have the following table:

```
drop table stg_json_structure;
create table stg_json_structure
(
    id          bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    meta_data   varchar(500),
    meta_value  longtext,
    parent_id   bigint,
    type        varchar(100),
    array_index int,
    created     datetime,
    foreign key (parent_id) references stg_json_structure(id)
)
```

where :

```
id - PK
meta_data - Json key
meta_data - Json value
array_index - if it's Array type when put here array index
created - timestamp of inserted record
```

So parent_id should point to the ID of parent key in json file.

I write the following Java code to read the Json file recursive.

```
// 1
public static void undefinedJson() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       

    try {
        JsonParser parser = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(new File("/tmp/test_json.txt"));

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            System.out.println(parser.getCurrentToken());
            if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(parser.getCurrentToken())) {
                JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
                readJsonArrayNode(node);
            }
            else if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(parser.getCurrentToken())) {
                JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
                readJsonObjectNode(node);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// 2
public static void readJsonArrayNode(JsonNode node) {
    if (node.isArray()) {
        for (int i=0;i<node.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("array index="+i);

            JsonNode child = node.get(i);

            if (child.isObject()) {
                readJsonObjectNode(child);
            }
            else if (child.isArray()) {
                readJsonArrayNode(child);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

// 3
public static void readJsonObjectNode(JsonNode node) {

    if (node.isObject()) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> i=node.getFields();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> jsonNode=i.next();               

            String key = jsonNode.getKey();
            JsonNode temp = jsonNode.getValue();                

            if (temp.isArray()) {
                System.out.print(key+"=");
                System.out.println(temp);

                readJsonArrayNode(temp);
            }
            else if (temp.isObject()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("ObjectNode");
                System.out.print(key+"=");
                System.out.println(temp);

                readJsonObjectNode(temp);
            }
            else {
                if (temp.isValueNode()) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("ValueNode");
                    System.out.print(key+"=");
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//4
public static void main(String[] args) {
    undefinedJson();
}
```

Now my problem how ca I get parent_id for child node ? Check above table I need have it to insert into database.

Comment: You _are_ aware that a JSON value can also be a primitive type, right?

Comment: yes, you mean need add additional check in readJsonObjectNode for that ? basically this is not such important for me ... I need to know how to handle parent_id and current_id/child_id

Comment: guys, any idea how to keep the id of each json key?